# Unable to install ruby 2.4.1 with rvm curl command

Tags: ruby, rvm

On a fresh AWS Ubuntu 20.04 server I am getting a failed ruby download error

It looks like stable works fine, and if I install 2.4.1 after the stable is installed it seems to work, but then I was getting some other weird issues after I went to uninstall ruby 3.0.0 (stable) and use ruby 2.4.1 as the default

```sh
## Step 1
$ sudo apt update -y
$ sudo apt upgrade -y

## Step 2 - install RVM/Ruby 2.4.1
$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s 2.4.1 --ruby
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/2.4.1.tar.gz
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 

Could not download 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/2.4.1.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '22'.

Downloading https://bitbucket.org/mpapis/rvm/get/2.4.1.tar.gz
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 

Could not download 'https://bitbucket.org/mpapis/rvm/get/2.4.1.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '22'.
```

Comment: Hang on, wait a minute?.... What's this line? `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s 2.4.1 --ruby`? Isn't that saying "install version 2.4.1 **of RMV** (which doesn't exist!! Hence why you're seeing a "404 not found" error message.)?

Comment: [The documentation says](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) to run `... | bash` to install the development version of rvm, or `...| bash -s stable` to download the latest stable version of rvm.

Comment: Once rvm in installed, you can then use rvm to install one or more ruby versions, such as `ruby v2.4.1`.

Comment: The [latest version of rvm](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases), at the time of writing, is `1.29.12`. This has got nothing to do with the ruby version.

Comment: I *think* you might also be able to add an inline `--ruby=2.4.1` to the command, but I'm not 100% sure; you'd need to try that yourself.